# ssh-keygen with expect in 1 command line and no passphrase

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to have one command line to execute ssh-keygen and generate the keys with no further user input (no passphrase)

I'd expect this to have been enough

```
expect -d -c "spawn ssh-keygen; expect -re {.*: } { send '\n' }; expect -re {.*: } { send '\n' }; expect -re {.*: } { send '\n' }"
```

However after the final step, it simply exits.

Attempting one more layer

```
expect -d -c "spawn ssh-keygen; expect -re {.*: } { send '\n' }; expect -re {.*: } { send '\n' }; expect -re {.*: } { send '\n' }; expect -re {.*: } { send '\n' }"
```

It complains `Saving key "'" failed: passphrase is too short (minimum five characters)`

Why does expect ssh-keygen command exits on the first attempt without completing?

Why does ssh-keygen complains that he received "'" when he supposedly received \n?

Comment: Try `interact` at the end of your script.

Comment: If you don't need to actually interact with the spawned process, use `expect eof` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a one-liner try

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh-keygen; expect : { send \n; exp_continue} eof'
```

Strings in expect do not use `'` for quoting. You can use `""` or `{}` depending on your string. The use of `.*` in the pattern serves no real purpose in this example, so you may as well just match on `:`. The use of `exp_continue` will loop through the same expect statement. `eof` matches end of file.

Comment: Why do we need to match eof?

Comment: In most cases if you don't `expect eof` then expect ends too soon and closes the connection to the command. This means you don't see all that the command writes, but sometimes the command also will be killed or die early if it tries to write. In this particular example, since we are in a loop (because of exp_continue), the eof is not really needed. The expect will stop either when the command finishes (and closes the connection), or after the default timeout of 10 seconds with no matching input.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `expect` for this. Just specify an empty passphrase with the `-N` option.

```
ssh-keygen -f foo -N ''
```

Comment: Good one. I'll accept the expect answer just because of the title. But I'll use this